# How to get objects inside ListView and assign it to a variable?

Tags: android, listview

```
SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, employeeList,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                new String[] { "Customer" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserPage.this);
                builder.setTitle(rocketName);
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure to accept this order ? " + listView.getItemAtPosition(position) + "SMS will be sent to the customer.")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    //Assign value to variable here.
})
```

How do I get the details of a particular position and extract one of the values out and assign it to a variable when the listview is clicked ?

Sample text in the logcat. One of the items in the listview:

```
26-John Smith
    Address: 41 Texas 55
    Time Frame: 5:00pm - 6:00pm
    Order ID: 5787
    Submitted at: 2015-03-15 11:18:23
```

I have tried the following method in `public void onItemClick`:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                                    String str = String.valueOf(tv.getText());
                                    String orderID = str.split("Address: ")[1].split("Time Frame: ")[0];
```

The reason it's not working is because it always display the text of the first position even though other position is clicked.

I want to extract the `Address` of that particular position in the listview when it is clicked and assign it to a String variable.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

    TextView tv = ((TextView) view);
    String str = String.valueOf(tv.getText());
    String orderID = str.split("Address: ")[1].split("Time Frame: ")[0];

            }
          });
```